# Non-sendable type returned by call from main actor-isolated context to non-isolated instance method cannot cross actor boundary

Tags: swift, swiftui

I use "RevenueCat" to work with App Store subscriptions, in the picture bellow you will see an warning message by Xcode, and I don't know how to fix it or even if this affect on the code implementation or not ?

NOTE: I use class with @MainActor

The code:

```
@MainActor final class SubscriptionManager: ObservableObject {

@Published private (set) var currentOffering: Offering?
@Published private (set) var isUserEligibleForFreeTrail: Bool? = nil

    func checkIsUserEligibleForFreeTrail() async {
        
        guard self.isUserEligibleForFreeTrail == nil else { return }
        if let package = currentOffering?.availablePackages.first {
            let productIdentifier = package.storeProduct.productIdentifier
            
            let results = await Purchases.shared.checkTrialOrIntroDiscountEligibility(productIdentifiers: [productIdentifier])
            
            withAnimation {
                self.isUserEligibleForFreeTrail = results[productIdentifier]?.status == .eligible
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The warning message:

[image]